# Given $\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ such that $\varphi(1)=6$, compute $\ker(\varphi)$ and $\varphi(19)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Given $\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ such that $\varphi(1)=6$, compute $\ker(\varphi)$ and $\varphi(19)$.

In my attempt I found that since  $\varphi(1)=6$ has order 5, then $\ker(\varphi)= \{5 \mathbb{Z} \}$ and since the function is homomorphism I got $\varphi(19)=4$. Am I right? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to conclude from $\phi(5)=20+10\mathbb Z=0+10\mathbb Z$ that $5\mathbb Z= \ker \phi$ (or first only "$\subseteq$", but there is no subgroup properly between $5\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$). But note that you "spelled" this statement wrong (no $\{\}$ here). But from $19\cdot 4=76=7\cdot 10+6$ you should obtain $\phi(19)=6+10\mathbb Z$. (I prefer to write "$a+10\mathbb Z$" instead of "$a$ in $\mathbb Z_{10}$", but that may be a matter of notation introduced).

Answer (score 0):

$ker (\phi)=5 \mathbb Z$ is correct. But $\phi(19)=\phi(1.19)=19.\phi(1)=19.4=76=6 $ in $\mathbb Z _{10}$

Comment: @Hagen:I have edited Show that φ(1)=6.Is my idea still correct for the case of φ(19)=4?

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. @nzobo

Answer (score 0):

@nzobo, you are absolutely correct. Im($\phi$) has order $5$ and so Ker($\phi$)=$5\mathbb{Z}$. Your second conclusion follows from $19=15+4$ so that $\phi(19)=\phi(15)+\phi(4)=\phi(4)=(6\times 4) ~mod ~ 10=4$

(This should be a comment but I can't comment.)